# live reload with grunt and typescript on windows

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, typescript, watch, livereload

I am trying to get grunt to reload the browser when it compiles the typescript. It is correctly watching the files and compiling them but I can not figure out how to reload the browser. I tried setting `livereload: true` in various places with no luck. I left the various livereload sections I tried below. i tried them one at a time and all together.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-typescript');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-livereload');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8181,
                    livereload: true,
                }
            }
        },
        typescript: {
            base: {
                src: ['js/src/**/*.ts'],
                dest: 'js/main.js',
                options: {
                    module: 'amd',
                    target: 'es5',
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: 'js/src/**/*.ts',
            tasks: ['typescript'],        
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            }
        },
        open: {
            dev: {
                path: 'http://localhost:8181/index.html',
                app: 'chrome'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['typescript', 'connect', 'open', 'watch']);
};
```

Comment: Are you including the live reload script on your web page per the docs?

Comment: Nope that was it. I installed the extension instead. The tutorials I was following never mentioned it. Post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're following the instructions for including the live reload script as documented [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html). An example would be to include this script at the end of the `body` (assuming the default port):

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```